# one-dimensional representation of the Free Group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, operator-algebras

I am trying to understand how (and why) the representation of a group $G$ and its (universal) $C^*$-algebra $C^*(G)$ entail the same information (just to let you know where the motivation comes from).

I will assume throughout that the group $G$ is countable.

To my understanding, a representation of a group is a group homomorphism from $G$ to some $B(\mathcal{H})$, in the case of a $C^*$ algebra it is a norm preserving $*$-homomorphism onto $B(\mathcal{H})$. Since a one-dimensional space is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and $B(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ (multiplication without zero); what we really want is a map
$$t:G\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$$
and/or
$$t:C^*(G)\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$$
that are the appropriate kinds of morphisms (respectively).

Now Since $t:G\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a group homomorphism so $t(g^{-1}g)=1=t(g^{-1})t{g}$ but if $G$ is finite that means that $|t(g)|=1$ otherwise the norm of $|t(g^n)|$ would increase, so all $t(g)$ must be unitary. So for any finite group $t(G)\subseteq S^1$.
(this is clearly compatible with the representation of $C^*(G)$ since we need to have $t(u_g^*)=t(u_{g{^-1}})=t(u_g)^*$; which means, in the group setting that $t(g^{-1})=t(g)^*$).
Now my first question is, what is the image of $F_2$ the free group under some (nontrivial) one-dimensional representation?
What can we say about $t(F_2)\subseteq\mathbb{C}^\times$, what is the maximal image this representation can give, is it still going to be contained in $S^1$ for example?

Comment: Should some of your $\mathbb C$'s should really be $\mathbb C - \{0\}$? For example $B(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$?

Comment: Actually, most of them, you are right I will correct it

Comment: I don't understand how your question relates with your motivation.

Comment: it is due to the fact that $F_2$ is not amenable and then we have that $C^*_r(F_2)$ is different from $C^*(G)$, but yes it is not necessary for understanding the question regarding the image of $t(F_2)\subseteq \mathbb{C}^\times$. So I'm trying to understand the 1D-representation on a concrete example where the group is not amenable.

Comment: Usually when dealing with topological groups we are interested in unitary representations or uniformly bounded representations. Therefore one dimensional representations (characters) of the free group correspond to the choice if two numbers from the unit circle. The characters are not sufficient for description of the group as the group is not abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write $F_2$ as a free product of two copies of the infinite cyclic group, $F_2 = \langle a \rangle * \langle b \rangle$ then a homomorphism $t : F_2 \to \mathbb C^\times$ is uniquely and freely determined by choosing $t(a), t(b) \in \mathbb C^\times$. Any choices at all are possible, and the image $t(F_2)$ will then be the subgroup of $\mathbb C^\times$ generated by $t(a)$ and $t(b)$. So in particular you can choose $t(a)$ and $t(b)$ to be *not* contained in $S^1$, which gives plenty of examples where $t(F_2) \not\subset S^1$.

One thing that's happening here is that because $\mathbb C^\times$ is abelian, any homomorphism $t : F_2 \to \mathbb C^\times$ factors through the abelianization map $F_2 \mapsto \mathbb Z^2$, and therefore $t$ is uniquely and freely determined by the choice of homomorphism $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: Does this mean then, that $t(F_2)$ is contained in $\mathbb{Z}^2\subseteq \mathbb{C}^\times$? (if I understood correctly)

Comment: No, it means that $t(F_2)$ is contained in a subgroup of $\mathbb C^\times$ that is generated by $2$ elements. Just to make up a silly example,  it could be the subgroup $\langle\omega^m 2^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb Z\rangle$ where $\omega = \cos(2 \pi / 17) + i \sin(2 \pi / 17)$ is the primitive $17^{\text{th}}$ root of unity; that subgroup is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z / 17 \mathbb Z) \oplus \mathbb Z$.